# Title over an image using Display:Table Cell

Tags: image, css, text, tablecell

I am trying to get a title to display over an image and have it center horizontally and vertically using display:table-cell.

A specific example is http://ollymoss.com - how, on hover, the title of each poster comes up and is centered vertically/horizontally. I inspected element and saw they were using Display: Table-cell but I can't replicate it.

If anyone happens to know a way to make this work, that would be great!

This is the page in question: http://sathyaram.com/graphic

I'm trying to get those titles for each tile to appear ON the tile, centered vertically/horizontally.

If there's a better method than display:table-cell, I would love to know! I know you can use position:absolutes/relatives, but I would like it to be responsive and I'm not sure how that'd work!

I'm trying to do this specifically within CSS - not sure how to use jQuery!

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should include a [mcve] _in your question_; simply linking to off-site code, especially a web site you INTEND to change, will not help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the title centered horizontally and vertically, you can make this in css I think :

```
.yourTitleWrap {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px /* with 50px for example ... */
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
}
```

For the top value, 25px represents height / 2, normally it should work and center your title in the center of the parent's div.